# Android InputStream Internet Disconnect

Tags: java, android, http, inputstream, disconnect

In my Android program, I have some code that downloads a file. This works fine, but since on a cell phone, you can be disconnected at any time, I need to change it do it reconnects and resumes the download when you are halfway through and somebody calls/you lose cell reception/etc. I cannot figure out how to detect the InputStream has stopped working. See the code below:

```
InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8024];
    int len1 = 0;

    while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
        Log("-"+len1+"- Downloaded.");
        f.write(buffer,0, len1);
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
```

When I lose internet connection, My log shows:

```
Log: -8024- Downloaded.
Log: -8024- Downloaded.
Log: -8024- Downloaded.
Log: -8024- Downloaded.
Log: -6024- Downloaded. (some lower number)
```

And then my program just hangs on the while( (len1 = etc. I need to make it so when the internet gets disconnected I wait for the internet to be connected again and then resume the download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html

EDIT (based on comment):
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=72378

So thoughts based on the above.... you might put the reading in a thread and periodically check to see if the thread has stopped reading data (update a shared variable probably).  If it has kill the connection and the thread and deal with it however you need to.

Another alternative is to not use the HTTPURLConnection and deal with the bits you need your self.

Comment: Hi,
thanks but I have a HTTPURLconnection - how do you get the SocketChannel from that? Thanks,